# ImportError with standard library package (Python 3.8.2)

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror

I wrote a few modules using PyCharm and when running the code inside the app, everything was fine. As long as I developed the modules I used an Anaconda environment (Python v. 3.8.2). I structured my project as follows:

```
env.py
tools
- __init__.py
- module_a.py
- module_b.py
- module_c.py
```

The `__init__.py` contains the modules as imports:

```
from .module_a import function_a
from .module_b import function_b
from .module_c import function_c
from .module_c import function_d
```

Some of the modules use third party and standard library imports e.g. pathlib or gdal. `env.py` imports `tools` and runs some functions from there.
In order to run the code from a virtual machine, I saved the Anaconda environment as .yml and "installed" it on the VM. So far so good, but when I run the code with:

```
$: cd ~/to_the_py_directory
$: conda activate someenv
(someenv)$: python env.py
```

I get `ImportError: No module named pathlib`

Which is confusing for me as pathlib is a standard library package. Can anybody help with this?

Some specs:
Debian 9.12
Conda 4.8.4
Python 3.8.2

As suggested by @barny I added `sys.version_info`. The output is as follows:

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Comment: can you run `which python` to see which version of python is being used and run `pip freeze` to see what packages are there in your venv and see if pathlib is actually there.

Comment: @Banks `which python` after activating the environment points to `/home/USER/anaconda3/env/someenv/bin/python` and `pip freeze` results in: `certifi==2020.11.8   GDAL==2.3.3   mkl-fft==1.2.0   mkl-random==1.1.1   mkl-service==2.3.0   numpy @ file:...   six @ file:....`

Comment: `python --version` I the command you should run. `pathlib` isn't standard on earlier versions of python

Comment: There is a chance you might be using <python3. It isn't clear. Try running `python --version` in your terminal

Comment: @Dallan & @Banks I checked the version before I asked the question. `python --version` results in `Python 3.8.2`.

Comment: can you put the entire traceback in the question

Comment: @ Banks `Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "env.py", line 1, in <module>   
    import tools as t    
  File "/home/USER/project/tools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>    
    from .module_a import list_files    
  File "/home/USER/project/tools/module_a.py", line 1, in <module>   
    from pathlib import Path   
ImportError: No module named pathlib`

Comment: Add to your code: `import sys 
print(sys.version_info)` and edit the output into your question

Comment: @barny it also says version 3.8.2.

Comment: I created a `test.py` file in the same directory as env.py and I included a function from module_a.py which uses Path from pathlib. When I run that test.py I don't get any import errors.

Comment: Try run from anaconda prompt and not from terminal.

Comment: Another test is run python with your env activate and try `from pathlib import Path`

Comment: @AndréGinklings activating the env and running python with `from pathlib import Path` also works.

Comment: Maybe is a encode error. There is a invisible char in this line. Try rewrite the module_a file again (dont use the same file and dont copy the content). Try to change pathlib with any other module in original file too (like math or os) and see if it works.

Comment: @AndréGinklings I also checked this. Couldn't find one. I've uploaded the project, maybe you can find the error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5qtitlof9mwa4j/sandbox.zip?dl=0   I noticed, that the problem only occurs when I try to write on the VM.